# laravel composer app.php changes not getting applied

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I i.e. delete the whole content of my `config/app.php` file and save it, my application still runs fine, I can still use the aliases etc which were defined in the `app.php` file before.
What do I have to do in order to actually see the changes I made in my `app.php` file?

I use composer like that:

```
php C:\Users\****\Downloads\composer.phar //i.e. dump-autoload
```

where my current path in my windows console is the directory of the project `composer.json` file.

Comment: Are you using config cache (php artisan config:cache)? If you are using it you need to clear the cache with 'php artisan config:clear)'

Comment: try php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @javiStolz thanks alot! config:clear did the trick!

Comment: @peyman.H cache:clear threw following error: _[InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace._ . Should I worry about that?